# Style bug, for comments tab in user profile in Chrome

Tags: bug, comments, design, profile-page, google-chrome

**Browser information:**

Google Chrome.
I try it in two different computers, both with  Version 34.0.1847.116.

**Steps to reproduce:**

When you go to your user profile, then to the *responses* tab, then to *comments*,  and then you select the text of a comment it would look as the *Image 1* shows.

**Site information:**

I have only test it on Stackoverflow.com
The URL would be something like this:  `http://stackoverflow.com/users/<user-id-here>?tab=responses&sort=comments`

---

**Image1**:

[image]

Comment: Looks like `.comments {... padding-bottom: 10px;...}` is the culprit here...

Comment: where is it ? why only for Chrome ?

Comment: @TimStone Yeah, that the same bug !